# Using 'that' or 'how' after DESCRIBE

Tags: grammar, meaning, difference, subordinate-clauses

"Austin described the speaker performs three types of acts or statements when engaged in the production of speech acts."

My teacher strongly believes that the verb "DESCRIBED" must be followed by "THAT" in the sentence I've written above. Otherwise, there'll be a dangling problem. I disagree.

Do you really think not using a "THAT" will make the sentence grammatically unacceptable and ambiguous?

Comment: It would work if you would write _Austin described the speaker **performing** three types of acts_. Think about the difference between _the speaker performs_, which has a subject and a verb, and _the speaker performing_, which is only a noun with a modifier: in the _performs_ case, you have an superfluous verb.

Comment: So you mean it needs to be followed by "that"?

Comment: If you use _performs_, yes, the _that_ is necessary.

Comment: ! This may be a dialect issue, but "Austin described **that**" sounds very strange to me.  "Austin described **how**" sounds much more natural.  [Ngrams seems to bear me out.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=described+that+the%2Cdescribed+how+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdescribed%20that%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdescribed%20how%20the%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @M.N I've added some tags to your question and slightly fiddled with the question title so that people will be able to find the question easily if they search for *that* and *how* in the future. If you wnat to roll the edits back that's fine. If you just want my name to go away from under your post, if you just do a small edit and fiddle with a comma or something, it should disappear! :-)

Comment: @stangdon Quite so :)  I think I've explained why in my answer below

Comment: @Araucaria I really appreciate your comment. Regarding the changes you've made, as long as the question will be easily accessible to other users in the future, it's fine by me. No matter whose name will be under the post!

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Austin described the speaker performs three types of speech act. (ungrammatical)
> 2. <sup>%</sup>Austin described that the speaker performs three types of speech act. (awkward / not good)
> 3. Austin described the speaker performing three types of speech act. (different meaning)
> 4. Austin described how the speaker performs three types off speech act.

Sentence (1) is ungrammatical because the verb *DESCRIBE* cannot take a finite declarative complement clause without a subordinator (for example, *that* or *how*).

Sentence (2) is of limited acceptability. Many speakers will say that it is ungrammatical. While we do see such constructions in printed books, it's use is fairly restricted. It is probably best to avoid using finite declarative complement clauses altogether after the verb *DESCRIBE*.

Sentence (3) is perfectly grammatical. Here we see the verb *DESCRIBE* taking a gerund-participial clause as a complement. Gerund-participial clauses are common with verbs that take nouns as complements. However, this usage of describe is NOT good for the Original Poster's purposes. This is because when we use *DESCRIBE* with a gerund-participial clause, we are describing the action being performed. Here the content of Austin's description is not about the *manner* or *quality* of the performance or performer. The content of the description is *that* the speaker performs three different acts.

Sentence (4) is the best solution to the problem. The verb *DESCRIBE*, like the verb *WONDER* usually takes *INTERROGATIVE COMPLEMENT CLAUSES* as complement.

- Describe **whether you're going to be there**.
- Describe **what you did**.
- Describe **where you went**.
- Describe **who you saw**.
- Describe **how you feel**.
- Describe **how you escaped from Colditz**.

In the fourth sentence here we see the interrogative word *how* being used to talk about the quality of the person's feelings. The last sentence, however, is ambiguous.

The *wh-* word *how* is described by CaGEL as a subordinator. In other words, they say that it is the same type of word as *that*, *whether* and *for* (subordinator *for*, not the preposition *for*). Sometimes we use this word without any interrogative meaning at all. It means exactly the same as *that*. In other words we use it in front of a *declarative* content clause. So the last sentence there might mean *describe the manner in which you escaped from Colditz* or it might mean *describe the fact that you escaped from Colditz*. There is only a slight difference in meaning - but it *is* a difference in meaning.

Words that usually take interrogative content clauses as complement can often take declarative content clauses marked by the subordinator *how*. These do not necessarily have any interrogative meaning. The words *how* does not describe a manner here. It has no meaning at all. It just marks the following clause as subordinate, exactly like the subordinator *that*. Here are some examples:

- I know how you've been skipping class.
- It's obvious how she's taking him for a ride.
- He described how you've been really helpful this term.

These sentences are of course ambiguous. They might be interrogative and they might be declarative. However it is normally clear from the context which meaning is intended.

**The Original Poster's Question**

The Original Poster asks whether his example without *that* is really ungrammatical. The answer is, yes. We definitely need to use a subordinator after the verb *DECIDE* if we want to use a declarative clause. However, the version with *that* is not very good either! The best solution is to use the subordinator *how*.

Here is an Ngram showing the relative popularity of *describe how* and *describe that*. I've used the terms "*described how they*" and "*described that they*" for comparison.

[image]

Comment: Huh? First you write an answer that is partly off-topic, then you change the topic to suit your answer.

Comment: @Alexander I see the mods have edited out the **** from your comment. Please see my comment to M.N which I made when I did the proposed edit and his friendly reply. Thanks

Comment: To me, it just sounds wrong to say 1 and 2. This case is similar to 'want'. 'Want' also cannot take a clause as an object. Whether 'that' is inserted or not, both verbs just don't sound right at all in the case. Just have to avoid using such a syntax with such verbs.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

> Austin[subject] described[verb] the speaker[direct object] performs[verb] three types of acts or statements[direct object+prepositional phrase] when engaged in the production of speech acts[dependent clause].

So you have [subject][verb][direct object][verb][direct object+prepositional phrase][dependent clause].

Basically you cannot have another verb right after a direct object. When you add the THAT:

> Austin[subject] described[verb] **that** the speaker performs three types of acts or statements[dependent clause] when engaged in the production of speech acts[dependent clause].

Now you have [subject][verb][dependent clause][dependent clause].

In this case, *described* is an intransitive verb, as you wrote it it would have to be transitive.

Comment: Hmm, seems to be fine with the verb *know*. Consider: ***Austin knows the speaker performs three speech acts*** :)